# Using variables (database requests) in the config.ru

Tags: database, variables, google-analytics, ruby-on-rails-3, rack

I'm new to Rack and try to get my head around it running Ruby on Rails 3.0.0.beta4.

I'm starting a Rack app in the config.ru file but would like to use a variable there that is stored in my database. Is it even possible to get a database value back before the application is loaded or am I missing the point completely?

I'm using the [Rack Google Analytics](http://github.com/leehambley/rack-google-analytics) gem and would like to get the UA key from the database:

```
require "rack-google-analytics"
use Rack::GoogleAnalytics, :tracker => "UA-xxxxx-x"
```

Thanks!

Comment: Did you ever find an answer to this question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course you can do someting like that

```
require "rack-google-analytics"

require "active_record"
ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection ...
...

use Rack::GoogleAnalytics, :tracker => "UA-xxxxx-x"
```

but you should understand than all code over line

```
use Rack::GoogleAnalytics, :tracker => "UA-xxxxx-x"
```

will be executed only once, when your web server is starting

Comment: Thanks, feels like a heavy workaround to load ActiveRecord only to get one value but indeed, this will work. Suppose it will be faster to get it from a config file somewhere.

Comment: Certainly, you are right, it is bad idea to load ActiveRecord here in real project. I wrote it just for example.